# If with an OR statement

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to implement an OR function into my if statement. This is what I've got in my initial block:

```
 initial
       begin
           flag = $value$plusargs("a=%b", a);
           flag = $value$plusargs("b=%b", b);
           flag = $value$plusargs("c=%b", c);
           #1 if (z != 0| z != 1)
              $display("ARGUMENT MISSING");
           else
           #1 $display("a = %1b, b = %1b, c = %1b, z = %1b", a, b, c, z);
       end
```

I'm trying to make it so that if any of the arguments are uninitialized the program prints "ARGUMENT MISSING" otherwise it prints the binary values of `a`,`b`,`c` and the output `z`. However, I think I've made some error in syntax making it skip the if case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initial  
       begin  
           if($value$plusargs("a=%b", a) &  
              $value$plusargs("b=%b", b) &  
              $value$plusargs("c=%b", c) )  
             #1 $display("a = %1b, b = %1b, c = %1b, z = %1b", a, b, c, z);  
           else  
              $display("ARGUMENT MISSING");  
       end
```

This should display arguments and Z if all are declared. Else displays argument missing message.